# Gridview.Databind() no actualiza los datos

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Estoy realizando una aplicación en c#, y estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de actualizar la información que se muestra en el GridView.

Yo obtengo los datos a mostrar mediante el SqlDataSource definido en la vista:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="PRODUCTOS_CON_STOCK" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:XXXX %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:XXX.ProviderName %>" DataSourceMode="DataSet" SelectCommand=" select EAN, CODART.....  "> </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Cuando pulso un botón, se realiza una actualización en la BD, y quiero recargar el GridView con la nueva información, para ello, realizo un `gridView.DataBind();`, pero no se actualiza ni me da ningún error.

El GridView está dentro de un `UpdatePanel`, pero dudo que tenga algo que ver.

He estado probando muchas cosas, como por ejemplo:

- Volver a asignar el `DataSourceID` y hacer el `gridView.DataBind();`
- Poner el `DataSourceID` a `null`, hacer el `gridView.DataBind();`, volver a asignar el `DataSourceID` y volver a hacer el `gridView.DataBind();`
- Realizar:

```
DataSourceSelectArguments argumentos = new DataSourceSelectArguments();

PRODUCTOS_CON_STOCK.Select(argumentos);

gridView.DataBind();
```

- En el `UpdatePanel` poner: `updatemode="Always"`

Pero nada de esto ha tenido resultado en la vista.

Alguna sugerencia de que puedo probar?

Gracias

PD: La información si se actualiza correctamente en la BD

Comment: el botón guardar esta dentro del updatepanel? Ya intentaste agregado el botón en un posbackTrigger del updatepanel?

Comment: Si, el botón esta dentro del updatepanel y con el postbackTrigger, por eso que no entiendo porqué no se actualiza la información dentro del gridview

Comment: Sería genial que subieras una parte de tu código a github para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente he logrado solucionar el problema.

En mi caso, era que llamaba un método desde el frontend, mediante AJAX, cuyo metodo es un `WebMethod` de tipo `HttpPost`.

El error estaba en que yo almacenaba en `Session` el `GridView` y el `SqlDataSource`, dado que la información que obtenía era los mismos que tenía anteriormente.
Almacené en `Session` esta informción dado que al ser un `WebMethod`, se ejecutaba directamente ese método, no pasaba por el `Page_Load` ni nada, y el  `GridView` y el `SqlDataSource` eran `null`.

Finalmente, me decanté por probar a hacer un "reload" del `GridView` mediante un botón, y si se actualizaba la información correctamente, por lo que finalmente obté por ocultar el botón, y simular el evento click en JS en el método `success` del AJAX, quedado tal que así:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: pageUrl,
        data: JSON.stringify({ gridMod: gridMod }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function() {
            document.getElementById("<%= btnReload.ClientID %>").click();
        },
    });
```

Entonces, el evento click llama a `LoadGrid();`, el cual ejecuta:

```
private void LoadGrid()
        {

            DataSourceSelectArguments argumentos = new DataSourceSelectArguments();

            PRODUCTOS_CON_STOCK.Select(argumentos);

 
            eanList.DataBind();


        }
```